# @Value - always null

Tags: java, spring, null, config

I'm using the `@Value` annotation to assign variables a value from the properties file.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;

    //Code 
}
```

The class is annotated with `@Configuration`, and is 'initialized' via web.xml, where the directory for the environment file is also set.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>envir.dir</param-name>
    <param-value>/path/to/environment/variables/</param-value>
</context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>eu.nets.bankid.sdm.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

On startup all the values are 'null'. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can refer to http://www.ekiras.com/2015/07/spring-boot-reading-properties-file.html blog for reading property files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to configure a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and specify its location:

```
@Configuration   
@PropertySource("file:#{contextParameters.envi.dir}/application.properties")//location of your property file
public class AppConfig {

        @Value("${db.url}")
        private String url;

        @Value("${db.username}")
        private String username;

        @Value("${db.password}")
        private String password;

        //other bean configuration
        //..
        @Bean
        static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without explicitly giving the classpath? By f.ex. referencing to the directory given in the web.xml file?

Comment: @user16655 yes instead of `classpath:application.properties`, `file:////path/to/environment/variables/application.properties`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add this bean to your `context.xml` to load your properties from configuration file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="location" value="classpath:server.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Then you would need to import that context.xml to your configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")
public class AppConfig {
```

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. I don't have an xml file, the 'AppConfig' class is the configuration Java file.

Comment: @user16655: Then you can add this bean with @@Bean annotation like shown in Rafik's answer